# mysql into outfile creating error

Tags: php, mysql

**I am having problem with mysql out file.**

I am trying to generate a CSV file of table . I need to make it in fastest way due to huge data.

it's throwing error like this .

> Selection Error Can't create/write to file
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mydir/uploads/data.csv' (Errcode: 2)

this is my code . please help

```
$host = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "mydb";

    // open connection to mysql database
    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or 
                  die("Connection Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    $sql = "select user_id,email,username from `engine4_users` into outfile
     './mydir/uploads/data.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ";

    try{
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Selection Error "
             . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    catch(exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: the path is the problem . In question `'/var/lib/mysql/mydir/uploads/data.csv` and query have `./mydir/uploads/data.csv` is it right?

Comment: why not start with a safe path like `~` or something off of home or whatnot

Comment: thank you very much @ LifeTimeProgrammer . Error was in my directory